# Undefined Values Returning from Expo Image Picker

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-image-picker, expo-image-picker

I am trying to use expo-image-picker library to get access to the gallery and choose an image from the gallery and display it on the screen. But when I choose a picture, I console.log the result and it turns out that everything in the result is undefined.

here is the code :

```
const handleImageSelect = async () => {
        setImageLoading(true);
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            allowsEditing: true,
            quality: 1,
          });
      
          if (!result.canceled) {
            console.log(result);
          } else {
            alert('You did not select any image.');
          }
        setImageLoading(false);
      };
```

Here is the error message I am getting :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, The problem was with the versions of expo-image-picker, react and react-native. I reinstalled everything  by checking the warnings and it works fine now.